# How to project a grid onto a circle/torus using geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

Using this geometry nodes graph, I've created a grid of a simple "tile" mesh.

[image: a grid of tiles and the corresponding geometry nodes]

I want to project this grid onto (or restrict this grid to) the surface of another mesh (the parent of these nodes), in this case a 2d torus. A solution for a circle would work too.

[image: a simple torus]

I can't quite figure out how to reconcile the "points" output by the Instance on Points node with the geometry of the torus. Is there a node I can use? Is there a better approach altogether? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Do you mean something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWRKP.png ....or something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR0S2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just assume you want to get this result:

[image]

This is where the `Raycast` node comes in handy.

With the help of this node you send a "ray" from a certain point in a certain direction. If this ray hits an obstacle, a *Hit* is returned.

With the help of this value you can now selectively delete the geometry from which the raycast was sent:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Raycast was the ingredient I was missing. And yes, this is exactly the shape I was going for.

One slight difference is that I'd like to use a custom mesh (named "tile" in the screenshot) instead of the geometry generated by the Grid node. So my final solution with the addition of the Raycast node looks like this, for anyone curious: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmMXx.png