# Simple way to separate Text in blender

Tags: text-object

I am trying to make the whole alphabet together as one piece and mesh it, then make each letter its own item. When I do this with what I do know it makes each letter in 3 different pieces and you can then join those pieces back together but is there a easier way to just put in ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ and sperate each letter into once piece only so I just have the 26 letter alphabet in mesh?

Comment: You may want to try using Geometry nodes and / or placing text into a collection.https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303897/making-different-size-sieve-meshes-using-geometry-nodes

Comment: 3 different pieces? You mean top, side, bottom faces? Well, then after converting to mesh, go into _Edit Mode_, select all with `A`, then `M` > _Merge_ > _By Distance_ and then press `P` > _Separate_ > _By Loose Parts_. Now you have 26 separate letter objects. Only problem is they all share the same origin point.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using animation nodes (free add-on with tons of benefit):

1. create a text object with your letters
2. in animation nodes create ONE (!) node, choose mesh, hit update, enjoy result

[image]

[image]